# Can not get all searchAnalytics Data using Google Console Search API

Tags: api, google-search-console, google-api-webmasters

I am using Google Console Search API to extract the search Analytics data. I am using query() method for retrieving data.
                        **Parameters:**

startDate: '2017-05-10'

endDate: '2017-05-10'

dimensions: ['date','query','page','country','device']

aggregationType: byPage

rowLimit: 1000

startRow: 0.

It should give me 1000 records, right? But I am getting less no of records(853). what could be the reason?

While reading the documentation I have come across that when we use date in dimension group and if we don't have data for that day then the row is excluded from result set. Is this the reason?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do the result rows look like? I've never seen a query with that many items in dimensions. I only do queries with one dimension per query. I have a theory why you're not getting 1,000 records but I need to know what your results look like first.

Answer (score 2):

Check out my answer for getting more results here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/45628911/2527200

I noticed, that requesting for page and query at the same time results in less results. You should request only query or page in the dimensions.

Comment: I have aware of the documentation to get the query result more than default 5000 records. But, my query was about I am not able to get the record count I have mentioned. ie. if I set the limit to 1000 which is less than  max 5000 record limit I am not able to get 1000 records also. I am getting 700 records.

Comment: So, I explored a bit about it and found out that this is how the API behaves. I solution I have implemented is I am counting the number of records received in the first request and setting startrow with that value for the next request till all the records are pulled. Is it making in sense?

Comment: This makes sense but if you set the limit to 1000 and get less results, this must be because there are no more results.

Comment: I searched for this possibility also, but there was some cases where records were more than 1000 and in first request it is returning only 800. Do u think is it the issue on the google side?

Answer (score 0):

I think You can search for 1000 urls by one account. RowLimit is the maximum number of rows to return. The API does not support paged results. Default is 1,000

Comment: T I think by 1000 urls you mean 1000 properties per account. But I am using searchAnalytics query to extract statistics for single property only. Yes I know the API does not support paged results. Default is 1000 but I can give maximun rowLimit=5000. I figured out that I am not getting all data because the dimension grouping I have used is not correct. So instead of that I used dimensions=['date','query'] and used filters for make request against each query. This is working in my case.